# May I assume no bank conflict in compute capability 3.0?

Tags: cuda

As I am newly learning CUDA this late, bank conflicts seemed to be one of the restrictions in CUDA devices and should be carefully thought through. But while reading compute capability 3.0 in [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-3-0), I found

"A shared memory request for a warp does not generate a bank conflict between two threads that access any sub-word within the same 64-bit word (even though the addresses of the two sub-words fall in the same bank): In that case, for read accesses, the 64-bit word is broadcast to the requesting threads and for write accesses, each sub-word is written by only one of the threads (which thread performs the write is undefined)."

Does this mean that we can ignore bank conflicts for a CUDA application in CC 3.0 or higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found [an answer.](http://gpgpu.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/08-opti-smem-instr.pdf) It's not totally free of all bank conflicts in CC 3.0 but multiple threads can now access sub-words without any bank conflict. I believe this would greatly reduce programming effort for bank conflicts, especially on my projects.